# Python - Gradually construct frozen dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am using a frozen dataclass to ensure immutability and also so that it is hashable and can be used as the key of a dictionary.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
  bar: str = field(default=None)
  baz: str = field(default=None)
```

However, it would be nice to be able to briefly mutate the object only during construction. How can I gradually construct such a frozen dataclass? The following obviously does not work:

```
f = Foo()
f.bar = "hello"

if "h" in f.bar and "some other complicated condition":
  f.baz = "world"
```

Otherwise, is there another nice concise way of what I am trying to achieve? Many fields will be conditional based on results computed from other fields, so it would be very awkward to specify these fields in the constructor.

I could obviously create a variable for each field and default this to None, conditionally modify the variable, and at the very end, construct a dataclass instance from all the variables. But this would be very messy and I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Write a good ol' standard `__init__`?

Comment: variable per field not needed - just use a `dict`. `f = Foo(**attrs)`; done.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [`dataclass-builder`](https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-builder/) package.

```
from dataclass_builder import dataclass_builder

def build():
  f = dataclass_builder(Foo)()
  f.bar = "hello"

  if "h" in f.bar and "some other complicated condition":
    f.baz = "world"

  return f.build()

f = build()
```

This is very close to what I'm looking for. I've decided to wrap this into a nicer solution:

```
from dataclass_builder import dataclass_builder

def b(cls, build):
  obj = dataclass_builder(cls)()
  build(obj)
  return obj.build()
```

Now, we can just do:

```
def build(f):
  f.bar = "hello"

  if "h" in f.bar and "some other complicated condition":
    f.baz = "world"

f = b(Foo, build)
```

Alternatively, we can implement decorators:

```
from dataclass_builder import dataclass_builder

def b(cls):
  def decorator(build):
    def builder():
      obj = dataclass_builder(cls)()
      build(obj)
      return obj.build()

    return builder

  return decorator
```

This can be used like so:

```
@b(Foo)
def build(f):
  f.bar = "hello"

  if "h" in f.bar and "some other complicated condition":
    f.baz = "world"

f = build()
```

Comment: cool, I didnt know about the `dataclass-builder` package before. that's pretty cool, that it works on frozen dataclasses too! I was actually able to test this out and it does seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict to build up the arguments for making a `Foo`. Having a half-made Foo doesn't make sense, better to build it well made.

```
pre_foo = dict(bar="hello")

if "h" in pre_foo['bar'] and "some other complicated condition":
  pre_foo['baz'] = "world"

f = Foo(**pre_foo)
```

Comment: Wow that seems like a much better solution.

Comment: Keep it simple and pythonic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first prepare arguments
and then call the constructor

```
bar = "hello";
if cond:
    bar = "world";
pass
foo = Foo(bar);
```

But workaround, if you really want that,
is `object.__setattr__(foo, "bar", "4")`
I'm not sure if it is good practice to do it this way though.